# Y axis of chart doesn't update correctly in Billboard.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, billboard.js

There is a chart generated with [billboard.js](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/) and I want to update the min/max values of Y-axis.

For doing this, I wrote in html:

```
<span>
    Max:</br>
    <input ng-change="$ctrl.updateY()" ng-model="$ctrl.maxValue"></br>
    Min:</br>
    <input ng-change="$ctrl.updateY()" ng-model="$ctrl.minValue"></br>
</span>
```

And in JS:

```
updateY() {
    this.lineView.chart.axis.max({y: this.maxValue});
    this.lineView.chart.axis.min({y: this.minValue});
}
```

It works fine for the `min` value but for `max` it doesn't.

For example if I set the maximum value to `100`, on the Y-axis it is `1000`.

For `1000` it is `100000`.

For `10000` it is `1000000`. I guess it adds an extra zero but didn't find out how and where. For `min` everything it's working fine. Is this a bug?

Any ideas?

Comment: You are going to need to provide a reproducible example.  I tired to reproduce it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ChNSKoVENDXUEXwdF8Ye?p=preview) but was not able to.

Comment: Could you provide full generation option code?

Comment: @JaeSungPark I think it's too complicated to put all the code here, I solved the problem by using `range()` instead of `min()` and `max()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue is solved if it is used `range()` insted of `min()` and `max()`. For some reason it doesn't update correctly with the later methods.

```
updateY() {
    const maxNumber = Number(this.maxValue);
    const minNumber = Number(this.minValue);
    this.lineView.chart.axis.range({max: {y: maxNumber}, min: {y: minNumber}});
}
```